# laravel apiato структура проекта на два и более api

Tags: php, laravel, apiato

Всем привет, в проекте нужно создать два api, однин приватный для своего фронта, а второй публичный, они полностью разные, экшены для публичного апи нельзя использовать а приватном и на оборот. Как правильно в таком проекте сделать структуру, чтоб файлы не переплитались между собой, у также разделить роутинг, к примеру приватный должен быть на [www.example.com/api/…](http://www.example.com/api/%E2%80%A6), а публичный [www.example.com/api/v1/..](http://www.example.com/api/v1/..).

Сам проект на laravel apiato

Answer (score 0):

Да как угодно можно организовать, вплоть до отдельного домена.
Мне так кажется удобнее да же. `private.example.com/api/v1` и `example.com/api/v1`.

В роуте `Route::domain(...)` прописываете и в nginx вторую директорию сервер (ну если локально, то свои домены в свой сервер который используете указываете). Далее вешаете проверку на доступы (middleware) на каждую группу маршрутов и всё.

Если вопрос про контроллеры и прочие обработчики, то используйте модульную систему, для объединения в одну папку (как при проектировании пакета):

Например в `app` директории будут папки: `app/Api/Private` и `app/Api/Public`
А внутри каждой будет такая же структура как и в папке `app` проекта. `Http,Models,Console,Providers` и так далее. В результате мы получаем всё что относится к публичному апи в нужной директории и наоборот.

Если оба api используют общие вещи, например request некоторые или ещё какие-либо сервисы, то их выносите в обычные `Http,Models,Console,Providers` в папке `app` проекта.